# Consume web services c#/.net with certificates and setting up security, also without adding service reference?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, ws-security

I am new to .net and web services

It is possible to consume web services c#/.net with certificates and setting up security, also without adding a service reference?

If yes then how to do that

WCF or WSE?

How to add a security policy to it?

I have looked already to WCF, httpclient, X509store, certificates, WSE in official documents but didn't know to apply via code.

I need a response in string

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you want to add a service reference, since this is what this feature is designed for?

Comment: Hi @TomW, Thank you for comment, there is no particular reason just looking for a different way. How to call web service after adding a service reference with certificates and setting up security policy?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a service reference is commonly used to generate a client proxy, while generating a client proxy can be done by using channel factory. Therefore, according to your requirement, we just create a WCF server-side with authentication the client with a certificate, this is enough.
And the client manage to call the service by ChannelFactory, Here is an example.
Server-side(console application)

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:21011");
            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Message;
            binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Certificate;
            using (ServiceHost sh = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService), uri))
            {
                sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), binding, "");
                ServiceMetadataBehavior smb;
                smb = sh.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
                if (smb == null)
                {
                    smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior()
                    {
                        HttpGetEnabled = true
                    };
                    sh.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
                }

                sh.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "5ba5022f527e32ac02548fc5afc558de1d314cb6");
                Binding mexbinding = MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding();
                sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), mexbinding, "mex");


                sh.Opened += delegate
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Service is ready");
                };
                sh.Closed += delegate
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Service is clsoed");
                };
                sh.Open();
                Console.ReadLine();
                //pause
                sh.Close();
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
    [ServiceContract]

    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string Test();
    }
    public class MyService : IService
    {
        public string Test()
        {
            return DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        }

}
```

On the Client-side, we can consume the service by using channel factory.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Message;
            binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Certificate;
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://vabqia969vm:21011");
            ChannelFactory<IService> factory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(binding, new EndpointAddress(uri));
            factory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetDefaultCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.Root, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "5ba5022f527e32ac02548fc5afc558de1d314cb6");
            factory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "f0969c5725b2f142b7f150515ec2bd12bc45250b");
            var service = factory.CreateChannel();
            var result = service.Test();
            Console.WriteLine(result);

        }

    }
    [ServiceContract]

    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string Test();
}
```

Please note that there are many ways to use certificate. Here the client-side and the server-side are protected by the certificate, and the sever-side authenticates the client with a certificate, client should provide a client certificate when calling the service.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/message-security-with-a-certificate-client
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-security-with-certificate-authentication
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.